# Can someone explain why the extra ()?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript from freecodecamp and there is a function that I don't understand the meaning of the extra (), I will attach the code, sorry if this already been asked before

I know that I need to the () in order to get the outcome but I cannot explain the reason behind it

```
const sum = (function() {
  return function sum(...args) {
    return args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  };
})(); //what I am asking is (func....)(); what is the reason behind those 2 ()?

console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

The outcome is 10, which I understand the function, I just don't understand the meaning behind it

Comment: What's even stranger is why even do this,.   If the function sum was holding some sort of closure, then it would make sense.   But as is, it's just a pointless IIFE.

Answer (score 2):

It's an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) - it's a JavaScript function that runs as soon as it is defined.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE